# Anglesharp HTML parser doesn't seem to be parsing document deep enough to access desired element

Tags: c#, web-scraping, anglesharp

So I'm trying to scrape a website using AngleSharp and want to access a particular button that is nested deep in the site. I have logged out the parsed document html with `document.DocumentElement.OuterHtml`
but can only see so far into the document:

```
                <div class="l-propertySearch-paginationAndSearchFooter" data-test="pagination">
                    <div data-bind="component: 'pagination'"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

However, when I inspect the page in the web browser, I can see the additional layers necessary to access the button:

[image]

As you can see, the div with the data-bind attribute title "component: 'pagination'" open up further but doesn't display this in the log - this is why, I suspect, I can't retrieve the element.

I've experimented with `document.QuerySelectorAll("button"` and get back a list of buttons but not the one I'm after - it's like the particular block I want doesn't exist. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand that button you are looking for is created with javascript and does not exist in original source code. That is the reason you can't access that button with anglesharp. Right click on website and click View page source (Ctrl + U on chrome) and look for your button there. That is what anglesharp sees not html inside inspect element.